# verifying a list using moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Given the calling code

```
List<Person> loginStaff = new List<Person>(); 

loginStaff.add(new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"});

this._iViewLoginPanel.Staff = loginStaff;
```

What is the syntax for verifying that there exists a staff by the name of john doe and that there is at least one staff being set? Currently, all the examples that I've seen are pretty basic, using only It.IsAny or Staff = some basic type but none actually verify data within complex types like lists.

My assert looks like

```
this._mockViewLoginPanel.VerifySet(x=> x.Staff = It.IsAny<List<Person>>());
```

which only checks the type given to the setter but not the size or items within the list itself. I've tried to do something like this:

```
        this._mockViewLoginPanel.VerifySet(
           x =>
           {
               List<string> expectedStaffs = new List<string>{"John Doe", "Joe Blow", "A A", "Blah"};
               foreach (Person staff in x.Staff)
               {
                   if (!expectedStaffs.Contains(staff.FirstName + " " + staff.LastName))
                       return false;
               }
               return true;
           });
```

But that tells me that the lambda statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.
Then i got the idea of putting the statement body into a function and running that, but during runtime I get:

> System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a property setter invocation.

**Update:**
In light of the first two answers to use assert, I tried that method but found that even after setting Staff to a non null list, it still shows up in debug as null. So this is how the full test looks

```
[TestMethod]
public void When_The_Presenter_Is_Created_Then_All_CP_Staff_Is_Added_To_Dropdown()
{
    this._mockViewLoginPanel = new Mock<IViewLoginPanel>();

    PresenterLoginPanel target = new PresenterLoginPanel(this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object);

    this._mockViewLoginPanel
        .VerifySet(x => x.Staff = It.IsAny<List<Person>>());

    Assert.AreEqual(5, this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff.Count);
}
```

And somewhere within the constructor of PresenterLoginPanel

```
public PresenterLoginPanel
{
    private IViewLoginPanel _iViewLoginPanel;

    public PresenterLoginPanel(IViewLoginPanel panel) 
    { 
        this._iViewLoginPanel = panel;
        SomeFunction();
    }

    SomeFunction() {
        List<Person> loginStaff = new List<Person>(); 

        loginStaff.add(new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"});

        this._iViewLoginPanel.Staff = loginStaff;
    }
}
```

When i debug to the next line, `this._iViewLoginPanel.Staff` is null which is what's causing the null exception in the assert.

Comment: Are you assigning the constructor parameter to the class variable?

Comment: yes, i'm assigning the parameter this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object to the variable this._iViewLoginPanel

Comment: Can you paste the line of code in the constructor that does that?

Comment: sorry about all the updates but i've updated it again to show the PresenterLoginPanel and the constructor and how i call the function that sets this._iViewLoginPanel.Staff

Comment: Ignore what I said about reference/value - that wasn't it.  Give me a few minutes, I'll update with some more info.

Comment: It is to do with mock behaviour.  Loose behaviour returns null for non Setup properties, strict behaviour throws exceptions for non setup properties.  Change your mock object to strict and it will throw an exception saying you can't use Staff because it hasn't been setup.

Comment: YES that was awesome! SetupAllProperties was the key. I was fumbling around strict and loose but didn't go deep enough. Turns out though that i don't need to set strict behaviour, i can have loose behaviour and setup all properties just as well. Tested and it works. Reinstating you as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Joe - glad you got it working :) Yes I agree, I generally don't use Strict behaviour either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than using the mock's methods, you can use NUnit methods to make assertions about the contents of the mock object.

Once you've assigned the list to the object and verified it has been set, use assertions to check specifics, such as the item count and that the first object matches what you expect it to contain.

```
Assert.That(this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff.Length, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff[0], Is.Not.Null);
Assert.That(this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff[0], Is.EqualTo(loginStaff[0]));
```

**Edit**

After further investigation this comes down to Mock Behaviour.  The properties `Staff` and `Person` weren't setup properly.

Do setup them up, alter your mock creation to this:

```
var _mockViewLoginPanel = new Mock<IViewLoginPanel>(MockBehavior.Strict);
_mockViewLoginPanel.SetupAllProperties();
```

A complete code listing of a demo is:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface IViewLoginPanel
{
    IList<Person> Staff { get; set; }
}

public class PresenterLoginPanel {

    private IViewLoginPanel _iViewLoginPanel;

    public PresenterLoginPanel(IViewLoginPanel panel) 
    { 
        _iViewLoginPanel = panel;
        SomeFunction();
    }

    public void SomeFunction() 
    {
        List<Person> loginStaff = new List<Person>(); 

        loginStaff.Add(new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"});

        _iViewLoginPanel.Staff = loginStaff;
    }

    public IViewLoginPanel ViewLoginPanel
    {
        get { return _iViewLoginPanel; }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class PresenterLoginPanelTests
{
    [Test]
    public void When_The_Presenter_Is_Created_Then_All_CP_Staff_Is_Added_To_Dropdown()
    {
        var _mockViewLoginPanel = new Mock<IViewLoginPanel>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _mockViewLoginPanel.SetupAllProperties();

        PresenterLoginPanel target = new PresenterLoginPanel(_mockViewLoginPanel.Object);

        _mockViewLoginPanel.VerifySet(x => x.Staff = It.IsAny<List<Person>>());

        Assert.AreEqual(5, _mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff.Count);
    }

}
```

Comment: *facepalms* of course, i was focusing too much on learning moq and not enough on stock unit testing :)

Comment: Actually, i accepted too quickly, when I use your code, it gives me a object null reference because the Staff property did not get saved. ( I debugged to make sure it was being set but straight after it's set, the value is still null)

Comment: I've noticed you've got `_iViewLoginPanel` and `_mockViewLoginPanel`.  `Staff` is being set on `_iViewLoginPanel`, the `Assert` is being done on `_mockViewLoginPanel`.  I missed this the first time.  Are they supposed to be the same object?

Comment: I've updated my question with more detail, basically the mockViewLoginPanel is the mock that's been passed into the presenterViewLoginPanel. The iViewLoginPanel is a field of the presenterViewLoginPanel so in this case it will have the mockViewLoginPanel.

Answer (score 8):

You could easily accomplish this with Moq itself (also when you don't already have a reference to the expected result object) - just use the `It.Is(..)` method:

```
_mockViewLoginPanel.VerifySet(x => x.Staff = It.Is<List<Person>>(staff => staff.Count == 5));
_mockViewLoginPanel.VerifySet(x => x.Staff = It.Is<List<Person>>(staff => staff[0].FirstName == "John"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This checks that the staff count should be more than 0, that there should be at least one item that is not null and there is at least one item that has first name equal to Joe. if you want to compare the objects, you'll have to add a comparer.

```
Assert.AreNotEqual(this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff.Count, 0);
Assert.AreNotEqual(this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff.All(x => x == null), true);
Assert.AreEqual(this._mockViewLoginPanel.Object.Staff.Any(x => x.FirstName == "Joe"), true);
```